# Remove all characters except last n characters from a string

Tags: java, android, indexing, runtime-error, substring

i am trying to remove all text except last 10 characters but getting error in android

```
 09-15 16:22:58.146: E/AndroidRuntime(13630): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=228; index=263
```

but it is working on java when i tried it in separate class.
here is what i tried? can anybody tell me if there is any issue regarding substring in android?

```
String allchar = 
"PJGOGROG fnkmslkjsfsdmnsgdnklnsgklsgknlgrf jkghijgdlkjkgjdfkjgf kjlgdfkjlfdgfjklklj
kljfdkjlfkjldfdkjslkljdfskjlfsjkldfsjklkljs
fdsjklsdfkljsfdkljkhgfhhgdfsgkhdfskghfdskghfdsghsfdghafevbhfsvgydcgubcdmgycdgfehkhfeghjgh68
Alias12345";

    String  number = "";
    String reqtext = allchar.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    number = reqtext.substring(reqtext.length()-10 );
    System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: I tried your code on java, not android & it works, prints Alias12345

Comment: I tried your code in android app and it shows Alias12345 and also tried in java it gives same answer.

Comment: Good question, maybe it's dependent on the Version of Java

Comment: works fine for me, which version of java are you using?

Comment: yeah it is giving me answer also in java but in android throwing error!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if `substring()` doesn't work, you can try doing it manually:

```
String allchar = 
"PJGOGROG fnkmslkjsfsdmnsgdnklnsgklsgknlgrf jkghijgdlkjkgjdfkjgf kjlgdfkjlfdgfjklklj
kljfdkjlfkjldfdkjslkljdfskjlfsjkldfsjklkljs
fdsjklsdfkljsfdkljkhgfhhgdfsgkhdfskghfdskghfdsghsfdghafevbhfsvgydcgubcdmgycdgfehkhfeghjgh68
Alias12345";

    StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
    String reqtext = allchar.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    for(int i = reqtext.length()-10; i < reqtext.length(); i++)
    {
        number.append(reqtext.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(number.toString());
```

Comment: Well i will try this @Zhuinden

Answer (score 0):

```
    String allchar = "PJGOGROG fnkmslkjsfsdmnsgdnklnsgklsgknlgrf jkghijgdlkjkgjdfkjgf kjlgdfkjlfdgfjklkljkljfdkjlfkjldfdkjslkljdfskjlfsjkldfsjklkljsfdsjklsdfkljsfdkljkhgfhhgdfsgkhdfskghfdskghfdsghsfdghafevbhfsvgydcgubcdmgycdgfehkhfeghjgh68Alias12345";
String  number = "";
String reqtext = allchar.replaceAll("\\s+","");
number = reqtext.substring(reqtext.length()-10, reqtext.length());
System.out.println(number);
```

This code works fine for me in android.

Comment: This will throw an exception as well.

Comment: It doesn't throw one for me. Are you using java 8 for android?

Comment: it is throwing exception. so what way should i prefer? @Maroun Maroun

Answer (score 0):

Avoid declaring so many variable, try using :

```
number = allchar.substring(allchar.length()-10, allchar.length());
```

Comment: The OP wants the end of the string, not the beginning

Comment: yeah ryt :) @CocoNess